# MongoDB 3.2 Document Validation match "null" or "string" type

Tags: mongodb, validation, nosql

I'm new to MongoDB noSQL Database and new to Document Validation.

I want to specify for a collection that a field can be "null" BSON Type or "date" BSON Type.

I tried in the following format:

```
db.createCollection("users",{

   validator: 
   {
    update_at:  {$or:[{$type:"null"},{$type:"date"}]}
   }
})
```

MongoDB give me an errmsg: unknown operator $or.

I have also tried to specify for a collection that a field not exists or if it exists is of type "date":

```
db.createCollection("users",{

   validator: 
   {
    update_at:  {$or:[{$type:"date"},{$exists:false}]}
   }
})
```

MongoDB give me the same errmsg: unknown operator $or.

Can i achieve this result with Document Validation? 
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. Your syntax is little off.

```
db.createCollection("users",{
   validator: 
   {$or:[{update_at:{$type:"null"}},{update_at:{$type:"date"}}]}
})


db.createCollection("users",{
  validator: 
  {$or:[{update_at:{$type:"date"}},{update_at:{$exists:false}}]}
})
```

Comment: The second statement seems not work for me. It check "exists" operator but it doesn't check the type "date" in the second case.